# horizontal RecyclerView inside a vertical recyclerview is not working, onCreateViewHolder never called

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am showing posts just like facebook and in each post there is a image slider with multiple images, In my list first item is different then other items, so i am using a heterogeneous RecyclerView, here what I have done please see my code,

```
    if (commentList.get(position).getAttachment() != null && !commentList.get(position).getAttachment().equals(""))
    {
        List<String> imageUrl = new ArrayList<>();
        imageUrl.add(commentList.get(position).getAttachment());
        holder.getImageSliderCommentRecycler().setAdapter(new ImageSliderAdapter(context, imageUrl, new ImageSlideItemListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void imageClicked(int position)
            {
                List<String> imageUrl = new ArrayList<>();
                imageUrl.add(commentList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()-1).getAttachment());
                listener.showImage(imageUrl, position);
            }
        }));

        holder.getImageSliderCommentRecycler().setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    }
    else holder.getImageSliderCommentRecycler().setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

if condition executes but imageSliderAdapter never calls oncreateViewHolder or anything else...here is xml code please see,

```
      <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/post_photo_relative_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/comment_textview"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/about_doctor_fragment_doctor_photos_fragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

here is my adapterViewHolder ...

```
public class CommentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
private ImageView commentProfileImage;
private TextView commentName;
private TextView commentSpeciality;
private ImageView commentDeleteIcon;
private Button bookAppointmentButton;
private TextView commentDescription;
private TextView commentDateTime;
private ImageView commentLikeIcon;
private TextView commentLikeCounter;
private Button replyButton;
private RecyclerView replyRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView imageSliderCommentRecycler;

public CommentViewHolder(View itemView)
{
    super(itemView);

    commentProfileImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.photo_imageview);
    commentName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_name_textview);
    commentSpeciality = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_speciality_textview);
    commentDeleteIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_comment_imageview);
    bookAppointmentButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_appointment_button);
    commentDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_textview);
    commentDateTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_time_textview);
    commentLikeIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.like_imageview);
    commentLikeCounter = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.likes_count_textview);
    replyButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.reply_button);
    replyRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.replies_recyclerview);

    imageSliderCommentRecycler = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.about_doctor_fragment_doctor_photos_fragment);
}

public ImageView getCommentProfileImage()
{
    return commentProfileImage;
}

public TextView getCommentName()
{
    return commentName;
}

public TextView getCommentSpeciality()
{
    return commentSpeciality;
}

public ImageView getCommentDeleteIcon()
{
    return commentDeleteIcon;
}

public Button getBookAppointmentButton()
{
    return bookAppointmentButton;
}

public TextView getCommentDescription()
{
    return commentDescription;
}

public TextView getCommentDateTime()
{
    return commentDateTime;
}

public ImageView getCommentLikeIcon()
{
    return commentLikeIcon;
}

public TextView getCommentLikeCounter()
{
    return commentLikeCounter;
}

public Button getReplyButton()
{
    return replyButton;
}

public RecyclerView getReplyRecyclerView()
{
    return replyRecyclerView;
}

public RecyclerView getImageSliderCommentRecycler()
{
    return imageSliderCommentRecycler;
}
```

}

Code is very Complex therefore I am posting only chunks, because everything else works fine.... this image slider I have just added a day ago , at that time it works fine but now it's not......

Any help will be appreciate ...Thanks in advance

Comment: I have gone through almost all solutions but nothing works for me ... so please at least ask once before editing or referring as duplicate....

Comment: add your adapter / holder code and your activity please

Comment: @JonathanAste thanks for replying ..... the complete code is too lengthy too paste here .... I am setting adapter in first code block....

Comment: I can't see where are you setting data to your adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 2 days of struggle I finally figure out what went wrong.... Issue was with XML, I was using same Id for two different RecyclerViews, so it always find the first recyclerview and set its adapter and ignored the second one....the real reason why I didn't realize this neither the compiler because these two recyclerviews were in a parent relative layout container, these were not the siblings. Also I was adding first recyclerview by using 'include' tag.

here is what my XML was looking like completely

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_post_detail"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="controllers.marham.marhammed.activities.DetailPostActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/topcolor_red"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/light_blue">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/forum"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/backBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@color/light_blue"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/backicon"/>


</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/post_detail_activity_recyclerview"
    android:layout_below="@+id/topcolor_red"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/post_detail_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <include
        layout="@layout/layout_post_detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the rest of the code....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_post_detail"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/off_white">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:contentPadding="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/post_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/post_detail_activity_ask_ques_button"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"


        android:background="@drawable/draw_body_red_button_circular_corners"
            android:text="Ask Free Question"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/speciality_icon_imageview"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/post_title_textview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/post_detail_activity_ask_ques_button"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/speciality_icon_imageview"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/speciality_icon_imageview"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Title Of Problem"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/delete_post_imageview"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/delete_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/patient_detail_textview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/post_title_textview"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/post_title_textview"
            android:layout_below="@+id/post_title_textview"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Patient Detail"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/post_description_textview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/post_title_textview"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/post_title_textview"
            android:layout_below="@+id/patient_detail_textview"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
            android:text="Some Description"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/post_photo_relative_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/post_description_textview"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

    android:id="@+id/about_doctor_fragment_doctor_photos_fragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"

    app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>

        </RelativeLayout>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/post_time_textview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/post_title_textview"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/post_title_textview"
            android:layout_below="@+id/post_photo_relative_layout"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:text="Yesterday at 12:06 AM"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/post_title_textview"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/post_title_textview"
            android:layout_below="@+id/post_time_textview"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/line_shape" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/post_number_of_answers_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/post_title_textview"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/post_title_textview"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="n Answers"
            android:textColor="@color/red"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="invisible" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/share_post_imageview"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/share_icon_red"
            android:textColor="@color/red" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/post_detail_activity_post_answer_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/share_post_imageview"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/post_number_of_answers_textview"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/share_post_imageview"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/post_number_of_answers_textview"
            android:layout_below="@+id/post_number_of_answers_textview"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"


     android:background="@drawable/draw_body_red_button_circular_corners"
            android:text="@string/post_answer"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I am posting this so that someone else out there could save some time. Thanks for reading...:)